# How to integrate Multiple clients using graphql hooks in react hooks

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, graphql-js

I wanna integrate multiple clients in my react-hooks application. I'm using graphql-hooks via Apollo client we have a module to integrate multiple clients

Following is the link Apollo graphql multiple client

```
    `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@titelmedia/react-apollo-multiple-clients`
```

Following I'm using for graphql hooks

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-hooks
```

How do we achieve the same for graphql-hooks?

My requirement is depending on the selection of the radio button I need to switch between these multiple clients all that in one component using more than one client.
In my app I'm using graphql-hook we wrap the component to the client here the same component has functionality wherein depending on the select one of the radio buttons the client must be switch.I'm having one client but need to integrate multiple clients I googled but i've not found so have questioned here. 
Is this possible?
Can anyone please help out there

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It looks like it should be fine to call `new GraphQLClient()` multiple times to get multiple `graphql-hooks` clients, the same way you can call `new ApolloClient()` multiple times to get multiple apollo clients. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: Yeah, In my app I'm using graphql-hook we wrap the component to the client here the same component has functionality wherein depending on the select one of the  radio buttons the client must be switch.I'm having one client but need to integrate multiple clients I googled but i've not found so have questioned here.

Comment: Yeah, in that case it's probably fine to call `new GraphQLClient()` multiple times to get multiple graphql clients.

Comment: which `GraphQLClient`? where is it??

Comment: @MohammadReza use graphql tool there you will find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use new GraphQLClient() multiple times to get multiple graphql clients

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good approach and you can follow it: https://www.loudnoises.us/next-js-two-apollo-clients-two-graphql-data-sources-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

I have two middleware graphql servers running. One for the app one for analytics. I do it in two different ways according to my need as below...

CubeClient.jsx

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { SchemaLink } from "apollo-link-schema";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const defaultDashboardItems = [{"vizState":"{\"query\":{\"measures\":[\"Product.count\"],\"timeDimensions\":[{\"dimension\":\"Product.createdAt\"}],\"dimensions\":[\"Producttype.name\"],\"filters\":[],\"order\":{}},\"chartType\":\"bar\",\"orderMembers\":[{\"id\":\"Product.count\",\"title\":\"Product Count\",\"order\":\"none\"},{\"id\":\"Producttype.name\",\"title\":\"Producttype Name\",\"order\":\"none\"},{\"id\":\"Product.createdAt\",\"title\":\"Product Created at\",\"order\":\"none\"}],\"pivotConfig\":{\"x\":[\"Producttype.name\"],\"y\":[\"measures\"],\"fillMissingDates\":true,\"joinDateRange\":false},\"shouldApplyHeuristicOrder\":true,\"sessionGranularity\":null}","name":"Product Types","id":"2","layout":"{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"w\":24,\"h\":8}"},{"vizState":"{\"query\":{\"measures\":[\"Sale.total\"],\"timeDimensions\":[{\"dimension\":\"Sale.createdAt\",\"granularity\":\"day\"}],\"dimensions\":[\"Customer.firstname\"],\"order\":{\"Sale.total\":\"desc\"}},\"chartType\":\"area\",\"orderMembers\":[{\"id\":\"Sale.total\",\"title\":\"Sale Total\",\"order\":\"desc\"},{\"id\":\"Customer.firstname\",\"title\":\"Customer Firstname\",\"order\":\"none\"},{\"id\":\"Sale.createdAt\",\"title\":\"Sale Created at\",\"order\":\"none\"}],\"pivotConfig\":{\"x\":[\"Sale.createdAt.day\"],\"y\":[\"Customer.firstname\",\"measures\"],\"fillMissingDates\":true,\"joinDateRange\":false},\"shouldApplyHeuristicOrder\":true}","name":"Sale Total","id":"3","layout":"{\"x\":0,\"y\":8,\"w\":24,\"h\":8}"}]

export function getCubeClient(location){

  const getDashboardItems = () => {
    //   return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("dashboardItems")) || defaultDashboardItems;
    return defaultDashboardItems
  }

  const setDashboardItems = items => {
    return  window.localStorage.setItem("dashboardItems", JSON.stringify(items));
  }

  const nextId = () => {
    const currentId = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("dashboardIdCounter"), 10) || 1;
    window.localStorage.setItem("dashboardIdCounter", currentId + 1);
    return currentId.toString();
  };

  const toApolloItem = i => ({ ...i, __typename: "DashboardItem" });

  const typeDefs = `
    type DashboardItem {
      id: String!
      layout: String
      vizState: String
      name: String
    }

    input DashboardItemInput {
      layout: String
      vizState: String
      name: String
    }

    type Query {
      dashboardItems: [DashboardItem]
      dashboardItem(id: String!): DashboardItem
    }

    type Mutation {
      createDashboardItem(input: DashboardItemInput): DashboardItem
      updateDashboardItem(id: String!, input: DashboardItemInput): DashboardItem
      deleteDashboardItem(id: String!): DashboardItem
    }
  `;
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        dashboardItems() {
          const dashboardItems = getDashboardItems();
          return dashboardItems.map(toApolloItem);
        },

        dashboardItem(_, { id }) {
          const dashboardItems = getDashboardItems();
          return toApolloItem(dashboardItems.find(i => i.id.toString() === id));
        }
      },
      Mutation: {
        createDashboardItem: (_, { input: { ...item } }) => {
          const dashboardItems = getDashboardItems();
          item = { ...item, id: nextId(), layout: JSON.stringify({}) };
          dashboardItems.push(item);
          setDashboardItems(dashboardItems);
          return toApolloItem(item);
        },
        updateDashboardItem: (_, { id, input: { ...item } }) => {
          const dashboardItems = getDashboardItems();
          item = Object.keys(item)
            .filter(k => !!item[k])
            .map(k => ({
              [k]: item[k]
            }))
            .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {});
          const index = dashboardItems.findIndex(i => i.id.toString() === id);
          dashboardItems[index] = { ...dashboardItems[index], ...item };
          setDashboardItems(dashboardItems);
          return toApolloItem(dashboardItems[index]);
        },
        deleteDashboardItem: (_, { id }) => {
          const dashboardItems = getDashboardItems();
          const index = dashboardItems.findIndex(i => i.id.toString() === id);
          const [removedItem] = dashboardItems.splice(index, 1);
          setDashboardItems(dashboardItems);
          return toApolloItem(removedItem);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return  new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    uri: "http://localhost:4000",
    link: new SchemaLink({
      schema
    })
  });
}
```

Dashboard.jsx

```
import { getCubeClient } from './CubeClient';
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

let cubeClient = getCubeClient()

const Dashboard = () => {
  const dashboardItem = item => (
    <div key={item.id} data-grid={defaultLayout(item)}>
      <DashboardItem key={item.id} itemId={item.id} title={item.name}>
        <ChartRenderer vizState={item.vizState} />
      </DashboardItem>
    </div>
  );

return(
  <Query query={GET_DASHBOARD_ITEMS} client={cubeClient}>
    {({ error, loading, data }) => {
      if (error) return <div>"Error!"</div>;
      if (loading) return (
            <div className="alignCenter">
              <Spinner color="#be97e8" size={48} sizeUnit="px" />
            </div>
          );
      if (data) {
        return (<DashboardView t={translate} dashboardItems={data && data.dashboardItems}>
          {data && data.dashboardItems.map(deserializeItem).map(dashboardItem)}
        </DashboardView>)
      } else {
        return <div></div>
      }
    }}
  </Query>
  )
};
```

Explore.jsx

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ExploreQueryBuilder from "../components/QueryBuilder/ExploreQueryBuilder";
import { GET_DASHBOARD_ITEM } from "../graphql/queries";
import TitleModal from "../components/TitleModal.js";
import { isQueryPresent } from "@cubejs-client/react";
import PageHeader from "../components/PageHeader.js";
import ExploreTitle from "../components/ExploreTitle.js";
import { PageLayout } from '@gqlapp/look-client-react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { translate } from '@gqlapp/i18n-client-react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faAngleRight, faTrashAlt, faPlusCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import settings from '@gqlapp/config';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getCubeClient } from './CubeClient';

let cubeClient = getCubeClient()

const Explore = withRouter(({ history, location,t }) => {
  const [addingToDashboard, setAddingToDashboard] = useState(false);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const itemId = params.get("itemId");
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DASHBOARD_ITEM, {
    client: cubeClient,
    variables: {
      id: itemId
    },
    skip: !itemId
  });
```

Titlemodal.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Input } from "antd";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { GET_DASHBOARD_ITEMS } from "../graphql/queries";
import {
  CREATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM,
  UPDATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM
} from "../graphql/mutations";
import { getCubeClient } from '../containers/CubeClient';

let cubeClient = getCubeClient()

const TitleModal = ({
  history,
  itemId,
  titleModalVisible,
  setTitleModalVisible,
  setAddingToDashboard,
  finalVizState,
  setTitle,
  finalTitle
}) => {
  const [addDashboardItem] = useMutation(CREATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM, {
    client: cubeClient,
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: GET_DASHBOARD_ITEMS
      }
    ]
  });
  const [updateDashboardItem] = useMutation(UPDATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM, {
    client: cubeClient,
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: GET_DASHBOARD_ITEMS
      }
    ]
  });
```

queries and mutations.js

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_DASHBOARD_ITEMS = gql`
  query GetDashboardItems {
    dashboardItems {
      id
      layout
      vizState
      name
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_DASHBOARD_ITEM = gql`
  query GetDashboardItem($id: String!) {
    dashboardItem(id: $id) {
      id
      layout
      vizState
      name
    }
  }
`;

export const CREATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM = gql`
  mutation CreateDashboardItem($input: DashboardItemInput) {
    createDashboardItem(input: $input) {
      id
      layout
      vizState
      name
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_DASHBOARD_ITEM = gql`
  mutation UpdateDashboardItem($id: String!, $input: DashboardItemInput) {
    updateDashboardItem(id: $id, input: $input) {
      id
      layout
      vizState
      name
    }
  }
`;

export const DELETE_DASHBOARD_ITEM = gql`
  mutation DeleteDashboardItem($id: String!) {
    deleteDashboardItem(id: $id) {
      id
      layout
      vizState
      name
    }
  }
`;
```